# RLP must be BytesLike

Tags: javascript, node.js, solidity, ethers.js

I a beginner programmer learning Web 3.0 Development, I tried my level best to deploy the following code on VSCode:

```
  console.log("Let's deploy with only transaction data!");

  const nonce = await wallet.getTransactionCount();
  const tx = {
    nonce: nonce,
    gasPrice: 20000000000,
    gasLimit: 1000000,
    to: null,
    value: 0,
    data: 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,
    chainId: 1337,
  };
```

Upon commanding node deploy.js, I get the following error:

```
Error: RLP object must be BytesLike (argument="object", value=null, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=rlp/5.7.0)
```

I was trying to deploy a smart contract raw transaction on Ganache using Transaction Hash but could not succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the binary data in quotes "  ".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).